# Copy Files from List With multiple UNC's to One Folder

Tags: powershell

I have a list of paths with PDFs, e.g.:

```
\\test01\file1.pdf
\\test08\file8.pdf
etc.
```

I'm trying to copy each of these files to one destination. I'm using the following script which isn't working.

```
Get-Content c:\copy\filelist.txt | Foreach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Source $_.FullName -Destination "c:\copy\"
}
```

I receive the error

> Cannot bind argument to "Path" because it is null

Comment: can you post the output of `Get-Content c:\copy\filelist.txt`...maybe just the first few lines will do

Comment: \\test01\t1\file1.pdf
\\test02\t2\file2.pdf
\\test03\t3\file3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Get-Content`, it is returning an array of strings, not file items. This should work, assuming each line contains a single filename.

```
Get-Content c:\copy\filelist.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -destination "c:\copy\" }
```

or as @Kiran said:

```
Get-Content C:\copy\filelist.txt | Copy-Item -Destination:"C:\copy"
```

Comment: I receive an error stating that a parameter cannot be found that maches parameter name 'source'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I figured it out,

```
Get-Content c:\copy\filelist.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "c:\copy\"}
```

Comment: nice...there is no need for foreach-object...just pipe it straight to copy-item like so...  `Get-Content c:\copy\filelist.txt | copy-item -Destination c:\copy`